# Angularjs 1.x controller not responding in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

So I am trying to separate my menu into a directive.  I have a very simple controller:

```
function Menu(){
  self = this;
  self.tab = '';
  self.selectedTab = function(tab){
    self.tab=tab;
    console.log('setting tab');
  }
}
angular.module('app.menu')
       .controller('MenuController',Menu);
```

and a simple directive:

```
function MenuDirective(){
    return {
        templateUrl:'Menu.html',
        controller:'MenuController',
        controllerAs:'menu'
    };
}
angular.module('app.menu')
       .directive('MenuDirective', MenuDirective)
```

the `app.menu` module is included in my `app.js`, and my directive is on my `index` as `<menu-directive></menu-directive>`.  The code in my `Menu.html` shows properly, but when I click on one of the links which look like `<li class='menuTab' ng-class="{'active': menu.tab === '/'}"><a href="#/" class='menuAnchor' ng-click="menu.selectedTab('/')">Home</a></li>`, my console log doesn't show, and my css doesn't work. Any ideas/hints? If I put it back on the index page instead of in a directive, everything is fine.  Using Angular 1.5.X framework

Comment: I'm pretty sure your directive controller property should be referencing a function instead of a string? I don't believe you can use angular defined `controller`s as a directives' `controller`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was the way I was mini-fying(?) everything. I was using gulp to bundle all of my javascript into one file, and all of my css into another, and I guess it didn't like that.  I removed my bundles, and added each file separately to my index and it works fine.  Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: If you're injecting any dependencies and want to minify, see http://frontendcollisionblog.com/javascript/angularjs/2015/03/31/something-no-one-tells-you-about-minifying-angularjs-controllers-until-its-too-late.html

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your controller isn't seen by your directive. What if you add the controller function in the same file with your directive and refer to it directly like this:

```
angular.module('app.menu')
       .directive('MenuDirective', MenuDirective)

function MenuDirective(){
    return {
        templateUrl:'Menu.html',
        controller: Menu,
        controllerAs:'menu'
    };
}

function Menu(){
  self = this;
  self.tab = '';
  self.selectedTab = function(tab){
    self.tab=tab;
    console.log('setting tab');
  }
}
```

Comment: I can absolutely give that a try.  I was hoping to keep them separate for reuse-ability (though I can't imagine what else I would use a menu controller for at the moment, other than this menu).  I'll check back in shortly. Thanks

Comment: Keep me informed for the result @Jared